# validation of javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string of javascript:

`#d1{width:100px;}`  it looks like css code

now I wrote a regular expression that finds of an element starting with `#` or `.` in the string.

the regular expression is like this:

```
/(?:(#|\.)([A-Za-z0-1\-]+))/g
```

and the above regular expression matches successfully such strings like the above one.

but now when I tested this regular expression on the above string in Google console with then it returns false

the which I wrote was:

```
var str = "#d1{width:100px} " // returns undefined
var regex = / (?:(#|\.)([A-Za-z0-1\-]+)) /g //undefrined
regex.test(str) // returns false
```

Why it is not working?

Comment: have you tried it without the spaces? `regex = /(?:(#|\.)([A-Za-z0-1\-]+))/g`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have spaces in your regular expression which you propably don't want there:

```
var str = "#d1{width:100px} " // returns undefined
var regex = /(?:(#|\.)([A-Za-z0-1\-]+))/g //undefrined
//           ^-------------------------^----- see, no spaces here
regex.test(str) // returns true
```

Comment: you don't need to go for capturing or non-capturing groups. Just `[#.][A-Za-z0-1-]+` would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. These spaces between / and parantheses are jerks.

```js
function regtest()
{
var str = "#d1{width:100px}" // returns undefined
var regex = /(?:(#|\.)([A-Za-z0-1\-]+))/g //undefrined
alert(regex.test(str));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="regtest()">Test</button>
```